# Postgres Pivot based on variable column to create a new id

Tags: postgresql, join, pivot

I have the following table

```
type     attribute    order
1        11           1
1        12           2
2        11           1
2        12           2
3        15           1
3        16           2
4        15           1
4        16           2
```

I need to understand which types have identical attributes and then assign them a new id. The order column can be as well if it's helpful because each attribute can only have one order, but you don't need to use it.

Ideally the result set would be the following where you have a new id for each type that is based on the attributes in the first table.

```
type    new_id
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
```

I was planning on trying to pivot the table based on the order column and concatenating the attribute id's to create a new id, but I cannot use crosstab and the number of attributes a type has could vary and I need to account for that.

Any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: How do you calculate the new id?

Comment: They just need to be new unique id's.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "which types have identical attribute/order combinations"?

Comment: I really just need to bucket the types based on the attributes. So all the types that have attributes 11 and 12 need to have the same new_id

Answer (score 0):

This works, there's possibly a better way to do it but it's what came to mind:

```
SELECT UNNEST(types) AS type, new_id
FROM (
        SELECT ARRAY_AGG(type) AS types, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS new_id
        FROM (
                SELECT type, ARRAY_AGG(attribute ORDER BY attribute) AS attr
                FROM t
                GROUP BY type
        ) x
        GROUP BY attr
) y
```

Output:

```
1;1
2;1
3;2
4;2
```

So first it gets the list of attributes for each type, then it gets the list of types for each common list of attributes (this is where it makes sure each type shares the same attributes) and gets a new id for each group of types. Then unnest that to put each type on a new row, and that row number is the new id.